# Visual Studio 2010 SQL Querys how to set BIGGER default font

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database

By default, the default font when you perform a query on a table by going to right click over table -> New Query is very small, you can increase it pressing ctrl+ but when the query is execute the font backs to the default small size. The same when you close the tab and does a new query.

I want a bigger size for always. I've search into options -> DataBase tools but nothing related found. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found.
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and colors -> Query and view designers